# How to use a variable name in ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following code which is part of a autocomplete ajax query. My code returns a JSON it's working fine with the attached code, however I would like to use a variable in place of the item*.d_name*  ie. I would like to make the auto complete function become more a boilerplate solution in which I can pass a variable to this function  and it would substitute the item*.d_name*, with the variable's value. I am having difficulty in trying to figure out how to do this.

```
success: function(data)  {
        json = $.parseJSON(data);

        response($.map(json, function(item) {
            return {
                label:  item.d_name ,
                value:  item.d_name

            };
        }));
        },
```

Comment: If accessing an object property with a dynamic name is what you're stuck on then the linked duplicate covers it. If figuring out how to pass a variable into the Ajax success handler is what you're stuck on then please leave a comment about that and/or [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: Thanks, it was being able to use a dynamic name, which is solved now appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this way,

```
var KEY = 'd_name'; // declare in somewhere or function param

return {
  label:  item[KEY],
  value:  item[KEY]
};
```

Comment: Thanks you perfect, must have had a brain freeze.